# F sharp or F natural from Minuet in G major

Tags: piano

I found scores of Minuet in G major on https://imslp.org/wiki/Minuet_in_G_major%2C_BWV_Anh.114_(Pezold%2C_Christian). But in some sheets, there's an F natural in the left hand of measure 29.

[image]

This appears to be different from the original. Is this an acceptable arrangement, or is it a typo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an error.

I found this F-natural in [this score](https://ks.imslp.net/files/imglnks/usimg/6/60/IMSLP08275-Anna-magdalena-04-a4.pdf), originally uploaded to the Mutopia Project [here](https://www.mutopiaproject.org/cgibin/piece-info.cgi?id=75). But the [change log](https://www.mutopiaproject.org/ftp/BachJS/BWVAnh114/anna-magdalena-04/anna-magdalena-04.log) of this Mutopia file clarifies that, in January of 2017, the maintainer addressed the issue:

> ```
> Date:   Thu Jan 19 12:14:28 2017 +0000
> Correct F -> F# in bar 29 bass
> Convert to LilyPond 2.19
> ```

Furthermore, you can see a clear F-sharp in an early manuscript source [here](https://ks4.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/8/85/IMSLP532969-PMLP357193-E475024_54-Partitur_D-B_Mus.ms._Bach_P_225.pdf).